# why docker container is not runnig in windows?

Tags: laravel, windows, docker

Help me friends, please. I'm a noob in docker.

I'm working with laravel an create project with Docker in location.

`root@VIGIA-PC:/mnt/d/projects/fastfood-app/fastfood-api#`

docker was working but when I shut down my pc, and then I turn on it, the docker container is not running, why?

[image]

when I go to to the project folder and type `ls` no appear files from debian terminal, when I going to windows they are here.

[image]

I runned `docker ps` and show the follow:
[image]

**Information**

- windows version 10
- distro linux debian
- build 19042
- Docker version 20.10.2, build 2291f61

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to change the behavior of your docker apps.

If the host is being restarted, so are the containers running on it : https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/

Comment: thanks for answer. what command should I use?? I think so the problem is that  project files in windows  are not shared with debian in wsl.

Answer (score 0):

I have already solved my problem.that was a problem from path